# Mocking puppeteer for testing

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, ts-jest

I have been working on puppeteer code to take screenshot of a website, writing unit test code with jest. My code is something like this:
**index.ts**

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export async function takeScreenshot() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const url = "https://someurl.com/somepage";
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForSelector("test");

    const buffer = page.screenshot();
        return buffer;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
}
```

There seem to be some ways to test puppeteer code, but I prefer my test code independent from the browser, so I decided to mock puppeteer like this article suggests:
https://cobaltintelligence.com/blog/jordan-mocks-puppeteer-with-jest/

However, the mock does not work as described. Actually the code itself described in the article does not work in my environment (node v18.13.0, jest v25.3.0).
After several hours of tweaking my mock, I finally came to the test code that works fine:

**index.test.ts**

```
import { takeScreenshot } from "../src/index";
import { stubPage } from "./mockPuppeteer";
import { Browser } from "puppeteer";

jest.mock("puppeteer", () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: {
      launch: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          newPage() {
            return Promise.resolve(stubPage);
          },
          close() {
            return Promise.resolve();
          },
        } as unknown as Browser;
      }),
    },
  };
});
jest.setTimeout(0);

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});

describe("action()", () => {
  test.only("it exports pdf", async () => {
        const screenshotSpy = jest.spyOn(stubPage, 'screenshot')
    await takeScreenshot();
        expect(screenshotSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**mockPuppeteer.ts**

```
import { Browser, Page } from "puppeteer";

export const stubPage = {
  goto(url: string) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
  screenshot() {
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
  waitForSelector(selector: string) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
} as unknown as Page;

export const stubBrowser = {
  newPage() {
    return Promise.resolve(stubPage);
  },
  close() {
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
} as unknown as Browser;
```

Now I have a working code, but the part for mocking puppeteer is a bit long, and not reusable for other tests. I tried other ways like creating a manual mock in `__mocks__` folder, and using spyOn. But the former cannot spy on the method which may limit what I can observe, and the latter requires setup for every method used in the main code.
My question is if there is any other solutions that the mock part can be reusable in the project, or better way to implement this?

Better way to mock a node module like puppeteer